# Nivo slider resize after loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, slider, nivo-slider

I have used the Nivo slider on my site and i have a small issue. When my web page is loading the images appear in their full size then they resize down to what they are supposed to be. Please could someone let me know why this is happening or how i can prevent this?

It's probably also worth mentioning that it is fine once the first page is loaded, it only happens when you load the first page - but as we all know, first impressions count!

The url is: http://www.urbanedge-promotions.com/

Thanks for your help.

Daniel

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, "questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself". Rebember this in future questions and please edit this question and add valid code.

Comment: try to add some code that contains the issue , use JSFiddle too will be helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**set a default with css**

add:

```
//stops the image from being larger than 100% width
.nivoSlider img {max-width: 100%!important}
```

or

```
//stops the image from being larger than 100% width
body .nivoSlider img {max-width: 100%}
```

or perhaps this, to override it in browsers that don't support `max-width` if needed:

```
//sets width to 100% by default
.nivoSlider img {width: 100%}
```

to your css, to override:

```
.nivoSlider img {max-width: none}
```

in `nivo-slider.css`